# Cloudflare not caching even after adding cf name server

Tags: cloudflare

I have added cloudflare name servers in my domain to use it as caching images and video.

But when i check in the below website it says that my website doesnt use cloudflar.

https://checkforcloudflare.selesti.com/?q=https://crewshield.com

Can you please suggest what i need to do for my website to use cloudflare

My domain is registered with 123reg and hosted in godaddy.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your name servers are set to hosteurope.com, not to Cloudflare:

```
$ dig -t ns +short crewshield.com
ns.hosteurope.com.
ns2.hosteurope.com.
```

You need to change your NS records to point to Cloudflare. You say you've done this but it looks like you haven't. Probably, something went wrong in the process.

See Cloudflare's documentation on how to configure your name servers: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205195708-Step-3-Change-your-domain-nameservers-to-Cloudflare

Comment: Have updated screenshot of whois.net output where it shoes that its cloudflare and 2 other ns of 123reg. Where do you see hosteurope.com?

Comment: I used the `dig` unix command, as shown in my snippet. It looks like {ns,ns2}.hosteurope.com are aliases for {ns,ns2}.123-reg.co.uk -- they have the same IP addresses. You need to remove the 123-reg.co.uk nameservers, so that Cloudflare's are your only nameservers. Currently the 123-reg.co.uk nameservers are taking priority.

Comment: But if i remove 123 reg ns(providers primary ns) than everything else would stop working like my mail server etc. Is it not possible to give all 4 and cloudflare still cache the data?

Comment: @Abhishek DNS doesn't work that way. When a client looks up your DNS, they will only contact one of your nameservers at random, not all of them. So all the nameservers have to serve the same info. The way Cloudflare works, you need to have Cloudflare as your authoritative nameservers. You can copy all of your existing DNS records (e.g. MX for e-mail) to Cloudflare -- look in the DNS settings on Cloudflare's side and add anything that is missing.